# Data only to show if input is touched - AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am making a simple program where the input data must show only if input is touched once. However, I cannot get the expected result as nothing is shown in span (Also, no error in console). Can someone help me out?

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Script Files --> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="text" name="person" ng-model="name"/><span ng-show="person.$touched">{{name}}</span>
    <script>
    //module declaration
    var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
    //controller declaration
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.name = "Enter Name";
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

> **Note:**
>
> I cannot use any form in this page. I have to calculate **ng-show** event with **ng-touched, ng-untouched, ng-prestine** - but without wrapping up in any form.

Comment: You should have a `form` as a wrapper of the input...

Comment: Then write your own logic and use `ng-click` directive..

Comment: Just curious, why can't you use a form?

Comment: The original inputs are inside the columns of a very complex table created by 1000s of peoples' data in rows. Also, the first row is of adding data in coulumns for a new customer. Difficult to manage form as then, there will be 1000s of them wrapping each row + 1 for the adding customer data row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only worried about form tag you can use ng-form attribute.

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- Script Files --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.16/angular.js"> </script>

</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <div ng-form name="myForm" id="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="person" ng-model="name"/>
  <span> {{myForm.person.$touched}}</span>
 </div>    
 <script>
 //module declaration
 var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
 //controller declaration
 app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = "Enter Name";
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```